# How to use PHP to get information about the user

Tags: php, networking

What kinds of information can PHP get about users? I would like to make a web page that shows information about whoever goes to it, like their IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, run
    phpinfo();
to find all the variables that may be interesting.

to get more, you should think about using cookies to see if the user is here for the first time. And use javascript to get some other stuff, like screen resolution, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can get anything in [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: Most of the data in $_SERVER is about your actual server, not an incredible wealth of information about the user...but yeah, that's where it's going to be kept.

Answer (score 1):

IP Address, User-Agent, Geo-Location based on IP Address, and that's about it without cookies and other data from other sites or properties.